# How to display a virtual attribute in a Rails Admin edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have users and sites with a `has_many through` relationship (`SiteUser` is the lookup table, upon which some role logic and invite logic hinges). I am using Devise Invitable to allow site owners to invite other users to collaborate on their sites. (sites is synonymous with organizations in my case).

But I also need to allow admin users (using Rails Admin) to invite users to *any* site. Site Owners in the frontend UI can only invite users to their own sites. But an admin user is an admin app-wide (not just site-wide) and they need to be able to invite users to any sites.

Based on the code I have already implemented, in Rails Admin, there is a form for creating a new `SiteUser`:

[image]

I can create the `site_user` here. But upon editing the `site_user` it doesn't display the email address. This is because `email` is a field on `user`, not on `site_user`. How can I get rails_admin to display the `user` email on the `site_user` record (given the relationship between them)?

[image]

I will share the code I have for `SiteUser` and `User` so it can help to make sense:

```
class SiteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RoleModel
  roles :ad_settings, :reporting, :video, :payment, :owner

  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :user

  before_validation :set_user_id, if: ->() { email != nil }

  attr_accessor :email

  after_create :assign_owner, if: ->() { site.users.count == 1 }

  def set_user_id
    existing_user = User.find_by(email: email)

    self.user = if existing_user.present?
                  UserMailer.notify_existing_user(site, existing_user).deliver_now unless Rails.env.test?
                  existing_user
                else
                  User.invite!(email: email, invite_site_name: self.site.title)
                end
  end

  def name
    user.title
  end

  def assign_owner
    roles << :owner
  end

  rails_admin do
    object_label_method :email
    show do
      field :email
      field :site
      field :roles
    end
    edit do
      field :site
      field :email
      field :roles, :integer do
        partial :site_user_role_select
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the relevant code for `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable

  attr_accessor :invite_site_name

  devise :authy_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :lockable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable

  include RoleModel
  roles :admin, :influencer

  has_many :site_users
  has_many :sites, through: :site_users

  def send_email
    if self.invitation_token.nil?
      UserMailer.new_user(self).deliver_now unless Rails.env.test?
    end
  end

  def my_sites
    admin? ? Site.all : sites
  end

  def site
    @site ||= sites.first
  end

  def name
    title
  end

  rails_admin do
    object_label_method :email
    modal do
      field :title do
        label 'Full Name'
      end
      field :email
    end
    edit do
      field :title do
        label 'Full Name'
      end

      field :disable_authy do
        label 'Two-Factor Auth'
        partial :disable_authy
      end

      field :email
      field :roles, :integer do
        partial :role_select
      end
      field :sites
    end
    list do
      field :title do
        label 'Full Name'
      end
      field :email
      field :sites
    end
  end
end
```

Also, `site_users` from `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "site_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "site_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "roles_mask"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

TLDR: What is the best way to get the `email` attribute from `user` to show in rails_admin for the associated `site_user` object?

Comment: I should note that it's not necessary for `email` to be EDITABLE on site_user#edit in rails_admin. But I do need to display the `email` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've posted tons of unnecessary information.

Your question is: ***How to display a virtual attribute in a Rails Admin edit form?***
(The original title was: 'Inviting a User to an Organization with Devise Invitable and Rails Admin')

```
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :email do
        read_only true
        pretty_value do
          bindings[:object].user&.email
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Read the documentation https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields

Comment: Thank you for that response - this works perfectly. I really appreciate it, and feel like a dumb dumb for not finding that information in the docs. I was having a hard time with some other related issues, for which I was pouring through the docs for and eventually sorted out, and didn't think to go back through to specifically look for this solution. So that is my bad, but thank you for taking the time to help me out. Classic RTFM, amirite? *grimaces*

Comment: Sure )  Always glad to help.